# how to fix listbox item titles?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

[image]I have a textbox and a listbox and would like whatever is selected in the listbox to be displayed in the textbox, but any item that is selected on the listbox shows as "system.windows.controls.listboxitem" instead of showing the words of the item.

This is my code:

```
    private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        texbox1.text = listbox.selecteditem.tostring();
    }
```

here is a picture, it's not displaying the title for the selected item.

Comment: Ravi this is something that you should be able to do / figure out with a simple `Google` search. try looking up the `GetSelectedItem` method

Comment: Are your code is compiled successfully ? I think it's should be listbox.Selecteditem.ToString();

Comment: here is MSDN site read it [ListBox Selected Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
    private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        texbox1.text = (listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: selectedtext doesn't exist. there is SelectedIndex, SelectedItem, SelectedItems, SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath.

Comment: how you bind the listbox with the data?

Comment: I added some items that are sentences